# How to prevent a user from directly accessing my html page by writing URL?

Tags: php, authorization

i want a hard coded Login Page (**login.html**), with no database. 
If a person writes correct username and password, it redirects to (**page2.html**).

Now my problem is that if a person write the URL directly for page2.html , he will be able to access it, without any login.

**Ideal Case** => www.example.com/login.html => if Correct => www.example.com/page2.html

**Problem Case** => www.example.com/page2.html => page2.html , NO LogIN :(

Comment: page3.html => no login. try again. or stay on login.html

Comment: Use session in php to check if user is logged in, and if not logged in then redirect back to login page

Comment: Can you not use php SESSION?

Comment: you can use session.... =)

Answer (score 8):

You can control all this with a php session like this

```
  //set the session on the login page
   $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;  

 //on the second page you check if that session is true, else redirect to the login page  
  if($_SESSION['loggedIn'])
      //allow
  else
      //redirect to the login page
      header('Location: /login.html');
```

A [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages. By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.

To make things simple, you can change your pages into `php` (e.g `login.php`).

- **Line 1:** In your `login.php` page, you will first check if the username and password are correct, if they are, set the `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true`
- **Line 2:** In your second page (`page2.php`), you will first check that the user did login by checking if the session have a value `if($_SESSION['loggedIn']) {//allow processing}`
- **Line 3:** If that session variable is empty, then this means the user did not login, redirect him to the login page `else { header('Location:/login.php');}`

Comment: i know that i will have to involve PHP for this, but the problem is that i have been an Asp.Net guy, and have no knowledge about php. 
So can you explain this process and replace the comments with code ?

Also i am confused about whether my pages will be in .php format OR .html format ? In some links, there is a separate php file which handles all the login process, but no one has mentioned the Baby Steps.

Comment: i edited my answer to explain the code, i am afraid this will be difficult to implement if you do not know anything about PHP

Answer (score 4):

To start off: I have no idea how you would like to compare the password and username with something and check whether it's correct or not, but for now I would do something like this (again, this is without database).

You have 2 options: Either use a session as stated above, or the bit easier way: Just use the`isset()` function.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="userName" required>
  <input type="password" name="password" required>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Send!</button>
</form>
```

page2.php will contain the next code:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']) {
  //direct back to a certain page, could look like this:
  header('Location: xxx.php');
  exit();
  //exit() prevents the code from running, it litterly EXITS the code as soon as it hits that line.
} else {
  //direct to page2.php
}
```

Let's break it down: Why did I use the extension `.php`? Because you cannot do this purely with HTML.

Why did I use `(!isset())` instead of `isset()`? Because a good practice is to think in security first, you don't access an important area and THEN check whether someone has lethal weapons or not. You check first and then you allow him either in or denie access. This is a quite simple and common way to prevent someone from accessing your page with the URL, however a SESSION is better and a bit more experienced practice.

Answer (score 1):

This problem cannot be solved with a pure HTML solution. Your question is tagged as php so I'll base my answer on that:

1. Post your form to a php script (such as login.php)
2. Script checks the login details and [sets a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)
3. page2.html must be php instead, and checks for the cookie before displaying the HTML

Another option is using HTTP authentication, see [this article](http://evertpot.com/223/) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You could block that page's access from external locations in your server securtiy settings,
then send the html of that page to the browser on successful login with `fil_get_contents('page2.htm')` in php.  the php is run on the server so the file request won't be from an external source. you could overwrite html on the page using javascript or you could `echo` the contents on an `if` in php that will show the normal page on `else`

eg

```
if(isset($_GET['Login'])
{
    //check login details
    //if(....) //put your login check logic here
    {
        echo file_get_contents('page2.html');
    }
    else
    {
        //normal page's code goes here
    }
}
```

> **Note**:how to set the file to disallow external access is outside the scope of my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this and it works perfectly: (in javascript)
Just put it at the top of the document.

```
var x = document.referrer;    

if (x == "page2.html") {
    console.log(x);
} else {
    window.location.href = "login.html";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

change the default path for your website by using complete path to login.php. Next time when any of the user will type your url, they will be redirected to the given path which is yourpath>login.php

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.net, perhaps you can use TempData. They stay with the session between pages.

```
if (/*username and password are correct*/){
    TempData["LoggedIn"] = "True";
} else {
    TempData["LoggedIn"] = "False";
}
```

Then, when your controller tries to load page2 you just check the value of TempData.

```
var validate = TempData.Peek("LoggedIn");
if (validate == null || validate.ToString() == "False"){
    return RedirectToAction("login");
} else {
    /*allow access to page*/
}
```

Using .Peek keeps the TempData, as it would normally be marked for deletion if it was accessed. You also want to check it for null as it may have never been assigned if the user does not first go through the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent that by checking if the user is already logged in

```
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...



if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        header('Location: login.php'); //here you put your login page
        exit;
    }
```