# How to prevent a user from directly accessing a page without using PHP

Tags: javascript

I am developing a login page, and I want to stop a user from accessing the user dashboard without first authenticating website.com > website.com/dashboard.html. When looking this question up, I found [How to prevent a user from directly accessing my html page by writing URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433253/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-directly-accessing-my-html-page-by-writing-url). The answer uses PHP, but my authentication system uses JavaScript to check whether the password is valid or not. However, JavaScript cannot be used along with PHP in a JS file. I have considered using PHP, but in order to use them together, I have to include my JS code in the webpage, which I don't want. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why not use AJAX to callback a PHP function? What do you mean you would have to include your JS code on your page? No matter what, you need to link to your JS in a file or inline it. People will be able to read it.

Comment: What is your back-end system written in?  The back-end system is what validates authentication.

Comment: @disinfor by webbpage, I mean the HTML file.

Comment: @Joe The backend is written in NodeJS.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-authenticate-users-and-implement-cors-in-nodejs-applications/amp/

Comment: Seems a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage to check if a user is logged in or not.

Set sessionStorage in the Login page and check it on the dashboard, if a session is not available redirect to the login page.

You can set a new key every time the user logs in for the session and check using API to avoid the same session value.

```
// Store

SessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = SessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: Can you change session storage client sided?

Comment: Yes! but the trick is-
authenticate the user on the login page using creds when creds are matched, send some random value back to the client, and stored it in the session and also stored on the server. and check and compare those values with the server and client on pages you don't want to access directly. On the next login that random number will be changed and nobody knows what it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I don't really understand the problem. But, I created a solution that might help.

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<form action="dashboard.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="username">
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password">
    <br>
    <button id="login">Login</button>
    <br>
</form>
<script>
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

> dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="username">Welcome user</h1>
<button id="logout">Logout</button>
<script>
    //Wait until the website has recvied a post request 
    //from the login page
    const usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]; //Change this to a 
     database
    const passwords = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3"]; //Change this to a database
    var results = ""; //The results of the thing
    const username = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("username"); //Get the username 
    const password = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("password"); //Get the password
    if (username && password) { //If the user has entered a username and password
        for (let i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
            if (username == usernames[i] && password == passwords[i]) { //Check if the username and password are correct
                results = "success";
                document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Welcome " + username; //Change the welcome message
                break;
            } else {
                results = "failure";
                document.location.href = "index.html"; //Redirect to login page if login failed change this to what you need this is just my case.
            }
        }
    } else {
        document.location.href = "index.html"; //Redirect to login page if 
    login failed change this to what you need this is just my case.
    }

    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Hopes this helps!